# What is the term for when "freedom of speech" drives away diverse voices?

Tags: terminology

I've read before about a phenomenon where a community's desire to allow unrestricted communication out of desire for diverse viewpoints actually has the opposite effect, driving sensitive and even moderate voices away from the community, thus leading to a homogeneous community in the other direction.

What is the name for this phenomenon?

Comment: It's a particular example of the phenomenon that people tend to become apathetic when they don't have to strive to improve their lot. An adage covering this is _familiarity breeds contempt_.

Comment: I recall a similar question in the last few weeks but can't locate it with any search terms.

Comment: This seems related to political correctness.

Comment: Would 'marginalization leading to homogeneity' fit the concept you're looking for.

Comment: No, it's more like "censorship of the masses"

Comment: I don't think there is such a term.  It's pretty subtle.  "Drowned out" is close, but lacks the extreme v. moderate angle.

Comment: I would call it "regression to the extreme."

Answer (score 1):

[Polarize](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/polarize): To cause a group to be divided into extremes.

This may not fully capture the context you are searching for (specifically regarding freedom of speech causing a directly undesired outcome), but I believe this describes the result of the phenomenon.

As [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/151125/233130) describes:

> Polarized opinions does not necessarily imply two opposite opinions, it implies two different opinions.

and while that may seem contrary to my point, it goes on to also say:

> Yes, they do tend to be mutually exclusive but they need not be opposite as such.

*Example usage (from the linked answer [emphasis mine]):*

> Our society is **polarized** with respect to abortion

Further, in a more scientific context, 
[Group Polarization (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_polarization): may describe the actual phenomenon you are describing (not just the outcome). In social psychology, **group polarization** refers to the tendency for a group to make decisions that are more extreme than the initial inclination of its members.